# Array to string conversion, with split

Tags: twig

I have a text like: 000325175
and I want to format it as: 000 325 175.

Nothing's easier (in theory) with the split filter, as:

```
{{ mynumber|split('', 3) }}
```

But I get a

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")
```

However I can apply a slice filter without any problem.

```
{{ mynumber|slice(9, 14) }}
```

So I don't understand. Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [split](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) filter return an array (with the spitted values), you should only iterate over the result to display it as follow:

```
{% for partial in mynumber|split('', 3) %}
 {{ partial}} 
{% endfor %}
```

[Here](https://twigfiddle.com/dmlbio) a working solutions

**EDIT:**

You can also use the [join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filter and concatenate the results as example:

```
{{ mynumber|split('', 3)|join(' ') }}
```